# What should I do to know if SSL is working?

Tags: nginx, ssl, http

I am working with NGINX, I just set up a domain and subdomain where I need to have SSL on both.

Look at the server block for the subdomain

```
server {

   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi  desktop.just4bettors.mobi;
   root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgambleweb/dist;

   ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/just4bettors.mobi.chained.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/just4bettors.mobi.key;

   ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
   ssl_session_timeout  5m;

   ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

   location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
        ...
   }

}
```

if I enter to that subdomain everything works propery, but, how should I know if the SSL it's been set up ?

Comment: You go to the site using SSL and see if it works?

Comment: hmm, all I am doing is entering ```www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi``` in the browser, what else should I do ? @ceejayoz

Comment: You just have to go to https://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi/

Comment: Your issue is something to do with the wildcard cert not liking having www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi.  But it seems to be ok with desktop.just4bettors.mobi

Comment: how can I set up the wildcards ?

Answer (score 7):

You can run the following tests:

1. `telnet $server_ip 443`

   this will tell you if there is something listening in that port

   ```
   telnet desktop.just4bettors.mobi 443
   Trying xxx.xxx.xx.xxx...
   Connected to desktop.just4bettors.mobi.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   ^]
   telnet> q
   Connection closed.
   ```
2. `openssl s_client -connect $server_ip:443 -showcerts`

   this will actually query the service and retrieve the certificates, you should be able to check the chain of trust using `openssl` as well.

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect desktop.just4bettors.mobi:443
   CONNECTED(00000003)
   depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   verify return:1
   depth=2 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   verify return:1
   depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   verify return:1
   depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.just4bettors.mobi
   verify return:1
   ---
   Certificate chain
    0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.just4bettors.mobi
      i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
      i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root  Certificate Authority - G2
    2 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
      i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
    3 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
      i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   ---
   Server certificate
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   xxxxx
   ```
3. use a third party service like the one provided by [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html)

Comment: ```mretana@mretana:~$ telnet $server_ip 443
Trying 0.0.1.187...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Invalid argument``` and ```mretana@mretana:~$ openssl s_client -connect $server_ip:443 -showcerts
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=0```

Comment: `$server_ip` is not intended to be _literal_.

Comment: in the 2nd step this what I get ```$ openssl s_client -connect desktop.just4bettors.mobi:443
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=0```

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Your domain doesn't work when I attempt to access it in a browser. Are you sure it's working at all?

Comment: yes, I am on it right now. you can try http://desktop.just4bettors.mobi/#/ or http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi/#/

Comment: @ceejayoz the www one does not work (it does not even resolve ...) but the other one does.

Comment: @dawud Neither one works for me.

Comment: that is weird, in my computer are working.

Comment: the SSL certificate I have to apply it to the domain only ? or to the subdomain too ?

Comment: @ceejayoz [can you `dig` it?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36nWNAvtwrw)

Comment: yes, desktop.just4bettors.mobi. 38400 IN A 190.171.28.156

Comment: @dawud I don't get any response with `dig`. http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=desktop.just4bettors.mobi%0D%0Awww.desktop.just4bettors.mobi&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers= doesn't show any either.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass your domain on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ it will test your sll and send back detailed  result. like bellow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That will only tell the OP if nginx is listening on 443/tcp. It will tell nothing about whether or not SSL has been set up correctly.

Comment: I eddited the awser

Comment: do I have to apply the SSL certificate to the domain only ? or also to the subdomain?

Comment: You have to apply it to both and there are certificate for that or your can havetwo  certificate for each. for more info look the following [link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18188/what-kind-of-certificate-do-i-need-to-be-able-to-sign-my-own-subdomain-certifica?rq=1)  .